# Dura Ace 7700 (with American Classic RD205 rear hub) Broke Shifter. Upgrade Options

Tags: cassette, shifter, upgrades

I’m currently putting quite a lot of miles on an older Canyon F10 carbon bike equipped with Dura Ace 7700 shifters, derailleurs and brakes. My wheels are American Classics with a newer RD205 hub, which according to American Classic supports 10/11 speed cassette.

Unfortunately, my right shifter broke and I’m quite short on options regarding 9 speed shifters. I could go with Microshift, which would be a significant downgrade as well as Sora.

I really love that bike but it’s a bit old for a complete 11 speed upgrade.

If going with 10 speed 105 5700 is the difference in shifting in comparison to 7700 big?

Any suggestions?

Comment: If your rear hub can be upgraded to accept modern cassettes, why not go to 11 speed? Used 105 and higher level 11s groups are not that expensive.

Comment: I need to change the whole group set then. However, I like the 7700.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep with 9-speed and Dura Ace level, options are following:

- New Old Stock. You can probably find and exact replacement on eBay or some shop that specializes on old parts.
- Campagnolo shifters, either 10-speed with Hubbub cable routing or Shiftmate 2 or 11-speed are compatible with Shimano derailleur and 9-speed cassette.

Comment: I like the second option. How accurate is Hubbub + Campagnolo regarding shifting?

Comment: If adjusted correctly, the derailleur position will be off by less than a millimeter at worst. 9-speed has enough tolerance to work well with that kind of error. I have 8-speed Hubbub hack on one of my bikes and it works just as well as with original shifter. The adjustment must be more accurate than with Shimano shifter, because you are using some of the error tolerance to the slight mismatch in shifting.

Comment: Thanks! It sounds quite promising. I’ll research the Hubbub hack. Do all new Campagnolo 10/11 speed shifters work with that combination?

Comment: Yes, all Campagnolo parts made in 2000s share the same cable pull ratios. The hubbub hack is for difference of one speed, and 11 speed lever with Shimano derailleur works on 9-speed cassette with normal cable routing. 10- and 11-speed Shimano derailleurs have different actuation ratio and the cable routing trick does not work.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, nothing shifts as well as Dura Ace 7700 or 7800. 7900 doesn't shift as well because the internal cable routing adds friction. And complex kludges like using a Shiftmate are not going to shift as well.  Period.  (Heck, since I have yet to go to 11, I still use Dura Ace 7800 rear derailleurs on most of my bikes...)

If you want to move to 10 speed, see if you can find some NOS 7800 shifters.  Barring that, you can also try finding some 5700 105 shifters.  Don't bother paying extra for Ultegra 6700 over the 5700s, though, as IMO the 5700s are just as good.  Again, though, the 5700s have internally-routed cables and don't match the 7700/7800 shifters in shift quality.  For me, they're good enough.

If you're happy at 9 speeds, though, just try to find some 7700 shifters.

Answer (score 0):

If you want 10 speed it's better to go with a new Tiagra 4700 groupset than old and inevitably worn 105 5700 (or Ultegra 6700) unless you find new old stock.

If you want the absolute cheapest keep-it-on-the-road option, a new Sora shifter will really not be too bad compared to a mid-90's Dura Ace one.

Comment: Ok, and what about a newer r7000 group set? I’m not so sure it is so much better than my current but old DA 7700. Therefore I thought finding a good and solid shifter solution would solve the problem.

Comment: The newest 105 will beat the pants off your old DA just due to the trickle down tech. Just the two extra ratios is worth it. In your situation with a frame and wheels you really like I'd probably get a full 105 group for it.

Comment: There is trickle down technology, but 105 still gets cheaper materials and production methods.

Comment: @ojs what would you do?

Comment: I stand by by own answer

Comment: Thanks. One more question. Is there any difference to Shiftmate or is it just a more convenient way to Hubbub hack?

Comment: Looks like Shiftmate 2 can be used to do the exact same thing. I haven't used one, but it looks like it's easier to set up than playing tricks with cable routing.

Comment: @ojs *105 still gets cheaper materials and production methods.*  If by "cheaper" you mean "different color".  Dig through some Shimano parts diagrams some time and you'll note that 105 and Ultegra share lots of part numbers.  I will grant that Ultegra cassettes are lighter than 105 cassettes, though, because to go along with that different color the Ultegra cassettes use an aluminum lock ring in place of the steel one used on 105 cassettes.

Comment: I believe the question was about dura-ace, not ultegra, lots of shared parts does not mean everything is equal and finally that aluminum and steel do count as different materials.